# Getting an error building static libcurl VS2019

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, nmake

First I make nmake work:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29812\bin\Hostx64\x86
```

then I `git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git --depth=1`

Then I run `buildconf.bat` all seems fine.

then I go to winbuild and run `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static` and the build fails with the following error:

```
configuration name: libcurl-vc-x64-release-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel
        cl /O2 /DNDEBUG /MD /DCURL_STATICLIB /I. /I ../lib /I../include /nologo /W4 /EHsc /DWIN32 /FD /c /DBUILDING_LIBCURL  /DUSE_WIN32_IDN /DWANT_IDN_PROTOTYPES  /DUSE_IPV6  /DUSE_WINDOWS_SSPI /DUSE_SCHANNEL /Fo"..\builds\libcurl-vc-x64-release-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel-obj-lib/altsvc.obj"  ..\lib\altsvc.c
altsvc.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\windows.h(167): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29812\bin\Hostx64\x86\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29812\bin\Hostx64\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Is my nmake installed wrong?

Comment: FYI: [Building static library for Windows (winbuild/Makefile.vc) should just "work"](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/5308)

Comment: @Scheff i think my nmake is installed wrong do you have any guides to do that

Comment: I suggest that you could go to the VS installation path\VC\bin by using cmd and execute vcvars32 to automatically set environment variables for the VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ultimate goal is to "Get a static library compiled with a local cl compiler", I suggest you try the "vcpkg".

All you have to do is "vcpkg install curl". It will download the source code and compiled locally. :)

Comment: just a question. is it possible to make it all into single .lib file (no libcurl.dll and zlib1.dll external files)

Comment: ok i figured that out `vcpkg.exe install curl:x86-windows-static`